# Website display shrinks - only on Chrome on a laptop

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome

I am  developing this site: https://angharadportraits.com/

It displays OK on all devices on which I have tested it, and on Chrome emulations of different displays.

EXCEPT - the client uses a Lenovo Thinkpad T450, with a display 1366 x 768px. On Chrome the display appears scrunched up to about a quarter of the intended size. Using IE on the same machine it displays OK! See screendumps below

It is in Wordpress. Initially I based it on the twentyseventeen template but, because of the problem, I rebuilt it on twentythirteen with exactly the same result.

I'd be grateful for suggestions as to the cause and solutions

[Display as intended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o25aD.jpg)   [Display on Thinkpad/Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHgUR.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client is zoomed out on their Chrome browser. (Notice the magnification glass at the right side of the URL address bar).

Comment: Thank you Sam - I have finally heard back from the client and that was the solution. Kicking myself for not noticing it! Thanks also @Jeremy - good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your viewport settings to `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1, , user-scalable=0">` The Lenovo Thinkpad T450 is probably scaling the page.

If you dont have a viewport tag yet you can add the code above between the `<head>` and `</head>` tag.

Comment: Idk why people downvoted this 2 times, without explanation. But @Sam Johnson's answer is probably right. But you might wanna do this so they cant scale, also this will take away the problem.

Comment: Thanks for removing it :)

Answer (score 0):

https://angharadportraits.com/how-it-works/

I checked this link and shrink the screen from my pc and inspect the code the css you have written cause and an issue check this link code where you have max-width issue. You added the child theme in that i see this css 131 line add like this

```
.entry-content {
    width: 60%;
    margin-left: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

you can see layout like this https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3137593/8d6459e40aec6c2a5f19a4f00d0b5379